# Meteor _lastSessionId is always different for the same tab

Tags: session, meteor

I'm experiencing something a bit odd and I can't make heads or tails of it... I'm using Meteor to send the sessionId to from the client to the server but on every refresh of the page, the sessionId I get is different, which shouldn't be, am I correct?

**Client**

```
Meteor.call('logSession', Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId);
```

**Server**

```
 Meteor.methods({
    logSession: function(sid) {
      console.log(sid);
    }
  })
```

Any reason why the sid is always different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_lastSessionId` is created for each websocket session between the client and server. It represents the websocket's session & state on the server side and not a cookie or something persistent.

When you refresh/open a different tab a new websocket would be created and this is why the session id is different.

Each Session ID represents the state of the data the client has on the server. This means the server 'knows' what data the client has on each session depending on the subscriptions so that it knows what to send down & what to change if something changes, for that particular tab.

When you refresh the page, you're using using a fresh new state so Meteor doesn't attempt to reconnect using a previous session id and restore your previous state, because there isn't a need to resume a previous state in terms of subscriptions since the user would expect the page to be fresh.

If you want to use some form of persistence available along tabs such as cookies use `localStorage` instead:

```
localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");

console.log( localStorage.getItem("foo") );
=> "bar"
```